# Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted. With big list

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to perform a cloud function that sends push notifications to all users in a list. This works well when the list is small. I think the problem is due to the number of calls I make to send the pushs. Any ideas?

Cloud function:

```js
exports.sendPushToUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, response) => {
    var promisesSendPushs = [];
    return admin.database().ref(Constants.USERS).once("value")
    .then((usersSnap) => {
        if(usersSnap.exists()) {
            usersSnap.forEach(userSnap => {
                if(userSnap.exists()) {
                    var user = userSnap.val();
                    if(user.firebaseToken !== undefined) {
                        var promiseSendPush;
                        if(user.platform === Constants.PLATFORM.IOS) {
                            promiseSendPush = pushs.customIOS.customized(user.firebaseToken, user.uid, data.title, data.body);
                        } else {
                            promiseSendPush = pushs.customAndroid.customized(user.firebaseToken, user.uid, data.title, data.body);
                        }
                        promisesSendPushs.push(promiseSendPush);
                    }
                }
            });
            return Promise.all(promisesSendPushs)
        } else {
            console.log("usersSnap undefined");
            return {code: 0, state: 'undefined'};
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("promisesSendPushs: " + promisesSendPushs.length)
        return {code: 0, state: 'pushs send!'};
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log ('Error getting documents', err);
        return { code: 1, error: err};
    });
})
```

Custom push lib:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function sendPushToUser(firebaseToken, message, uid) {
  if(firebaseToken) {
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        [ firebaseToken ],
        message
    ).then(() => {
      return { code: 0}
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { code: 1}
    });
  } else {
    return { code: 1 }
  }
}

exports.customized = function(firebaseToken, uid, title, body) {
  let message = {
    data: {
      title: `${title}`,
      body: `${body}`
    }
  };
  return sendPushToUser(firebaseToken, message, uid);
};
```

Console firebase error:

```
Error: function crashed out of request scope
```

Function invocation was interrupted.

Comment: Can you show some additional information about the crash? For example: when did the call start, and when did it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to send the result of all of these promises to the client:

```
return Promise.all(promisesSendPushs)
```

Cloud Functions might crash trying to serialize all the results from all the resolved promises, which could get very large.

Instead, figure out the response you want to send to the client in the event that all the promises succeed.  For example:

```
return Promise.all(promisesSendPushs)
.then(results => {
    return { the object to send to the client on success }
})
.catch(error => {
    return { the object to send to the client on error }
})
```

Comment: The problem: Cloud Functions crash trying to serialize all the results from all the resolved promises, which could get very large.

I solved it with a try catch after Promise.all and when sending each push I did not make any return, except the one that sends the push:

if(firebaseToken) {
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        [ firebaseToken ],
        message
    ).then(() => {
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
  }